# Webpack cli permission denied, Laravel + Docker

Tags: laravel, nodejs, docker

tengo un problema a la hora de montar un entorno de trabajo para Laravel usando Docker. Estoy trabajando con Dockerfile y docker.compose.yml

Mi problema es el siguiente:

```
webpack cli permission denied, open '/var/www/html/public/css/app.css
```

Esto sucede cuando ejecuto algunos de estos dos comandos:

- `docker-compose run --rm npm install`
- `docker-compose run --rm npm run dev`

En mi archivo Dockerfile tengo lo siguiente:

```
FROM php:8.0.5-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
RUN chmod 755 /var/www
```

Y en mi archivo `docker-compose.yml` tengo esto:

```
version: "3.7"
networks:
  clonestagram:

services:
  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['composer', '--ignore-platform-reqs']
    networks:
      - clonestagram

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - clonestagram

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - clonestagram

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'clonestagram'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - clonestagram

  npm:
    image: node:16-alpine3.12
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']
    networks:
      - clonestagram
```

Comment: estás ejecutanto el node run en el docker o en tu maquina?

Comment: En el docker. Todo lo corro en los contenedores. Ya que simulo un entorno completo en docker.

Comment: intenta darle permisos 755 al usuario desde tu bash de docker al fichero de nodemodules, debería funcionar